# git diffで自分が修正した箇所の差分のみを見たい

Tags: git

```
git diff branch1 branch2
```

上記のコマンドで差分を見るとき、branch2で自分が修正した箇所の差分のみを見る方法はないでしょうか。

Comment: 参考情報 [git diff with author filter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3509419/git-diff-with-author-filter)

Answer (score 5):

`git log` の `-p` と `--author` を組み合せて使えばどうでしょうか

```
git log -p --author=username
```